# Как при api запросе в next js получить один объект из массива?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, token, nextjs

Есть приложение в котором я с помощью api запроса с токеном получаю массив объектов с данными. Весь массив рендерится на странице. Далее необходимо получить какой либо объект из массива и отрендеристь уже детальную информацию из массива, и здесь начинается проблема. В методе getServerSideProps получаю вместо одного объекта массив со всеми объектами.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
   const response = await fetch(`https://api.json-generator.com/templates/SOMENUMDER/data? 
${context.params.id}&access_token=SOMETOKEN`)
   const job = await response.json();
   console.log(job);
   return {
      props: { job }, // will be passed to the page component as props
   }
}
```

Как я понял, суть в том чтобы в api запросе указать id интересуемого объекта и тогда можно будет с ним взаимодействовать. Но к сожелению все наоборот.